# Magento 2 | Get number of items in cart

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

I am trying to get items quantity from the cart.

I tried using this but it responded with unexpected results:

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getItemsCount(); ?>
?>
```

That returns a number of products in the cart but not the number of items.

Example:

> Product 1 - Quantity in cart (2)
>
> Product 2 - Quantity in cart (4)

The above would give me a result of 2 but I would expect 6.

**How can I achieve the above?**

*Magento ver. 2.2.4*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getSummaryCount();
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's not working when full page cache is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the checkout session. This is an example in a helper context, using dependency injection

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;


class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
        
        public function __construct(
               Context $context,
               CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
        ){
                 parent::__construct($context);
                 $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        
         }
                  
         /**
          * @return float|int
          * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
          * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
          */
         public function getCartItemsCount()
         {
                return $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty();
         } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cart = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$itemsQty = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();